# Run query while ignoring empty fields

Tags: php

I'm using input fields for extracting user inputs, which then will filter a query based on their inputs. 
I'm trying to make it so that if the user leaves one of the fields empty the query will still execute while ignoring the empty field.

For example:

[image: Input Fields]

Case1:

say the user wants to to filter data for just temperature, Humidity and Air Pressure. If I fill in the input fields and execute the query it will work.

Case2:

Now the user wants data for just Temperature and ignore Humidity and Air Pressure (but still present their values without filtering them). The query will fail because it's missing values.

How can I make it so my query can ignore those missing values and just use the given data?

Here's my approach so far (the if field is to check empty on other input fields not related to these):

```
if(empty($Y1) || empty($Y2) || empty($M1) || empty($M2) || empty($D1) || empty($D2) || empty($m1) || empty($m2)){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM sensors, sensorsdata WHERE sensors.SensorID = sensorsdata.SensorID 
        AND sensorsdata.SensorID = '$id' 
        AND sensorsdata.Temperature BETWEEN $T1 AND $T2
        AND sensorsdata.Humidity BETWEEN $H1 AND $H2
        AND sensorsdata.Air_Pressure BETWEEN $P1 AND $P2
        AND sensorsdata.Carbon_Monoxide BETWEEN $C1 AND $C2
        order by sensorsdata.Date Desc"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this (make a query string in steps and then execute):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM sensors, sensorsdata WHERE sensors.SensorID = sensorsdata.SensorID 
    AND sensorsdata.SensorID = '$id'";

if(!empty($T1) && !empty($T2)){
    $query .= " AND sensorsdata.Temperature BETWEEN $T1 AND $T2";
}

if(!empty($H1) && !empty($H2)){
    $query .= " AND sensorsdata.Humidity BETWEEN $H1 AND $H2";
}

if(!empty($P1) && !empty($P2)){
    $query .= " AND sensorsdata.Air_Pressure BETWEEN $P1 AND $P2";
}

if(!empty($C1) && !empty($C2)){
    $query .= " AND sensorsdata.Carbon_Monoxide BETWEEN $C1 AND $C2";
}

$query .= " order by sensorsdata.Date Desc";
```